# gradle - Create installation task for native library

Tags: gradle, installation, shared-libraries, static-libraries, native

I recently changed my build system of a C++ library I'm developing from make to gradle. I'm naturally using the `cpp` plugin. The compilation itself is working excellent so far. However there's one decisive thing missing I had in my `Makefile`: A task/target to install the library in the system.
*(For linux moving all headers to `/usr/local/include` and the generated `so` and `a`files to `/usr/local/lib`)*

I have a rough idea how to implement it under Linux *(copying the files to the right locations)* systems but no clue how I would do it for Windows. Also Google was not helpful so far.

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
model {
    platforms {
        x64 {
              architecture "x86_64"
        }
        x86 {
              architecture "x86"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug
        release
    }

    components {
        library(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            if(System.properties['sun.arch.data.model'] == "64") {
                targetPlatform "x64"
            } else {
                targetPlatform "x86"
            }

            sources {
                cpp {
                    source {
                        srcDirs "src"
                        include "**/*.cpp"
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDirs "src"
                        include "**/*.hpp"
                    }
                }
            }

            binaries.all {
                // Compiler options
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a note the output files are located under `build/libs/library/shared/release/library.dll`/`build/libs/library/shared/release/liblibrary.so` and `build/libs/library/static/release/library.lib`/`build/libs/library/static/release/liblibrary.a`

Comment: What exactly do you expect a `make install` or possible Gradle `install` task to do on Windows? Using Linux, you install libraries separately (in common directories) and applications can access them, if they need to. On Windows, most of the applications are delivered with their required libraries. It's really rare, that libraries are installed separately on Windows and, if so, they are just copied into their own directory (just like applications). Dependent applications need to search the libraries, either at an expected or an user-defined location.

Comment: That's kinda the question. When MinGW or Cygwin is being used the installation process is the same as under linux. Well when the libraries can't be put reliably in some system path then it might be a good idea to pack the libraries and the headers in a zip.